# Assiging base class pointer to derived class in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a base class called ModelBase and I have a derived class called "Person".
Now in the init method of person, I have something like

```
-(Person*) init {
     if(self = [super init])
         return self;

     return nil; 
}
```

However, Objective C complains that
Incompatible Objective-C types initializing 'struct ModelBase *', expected 'struct Person *'. I'm only initializing self with [super init] which is initializing a base class pointer to a derived class.

What am I missing?

Comment: What's your header look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you declare your ModelBase init method to return (ModelBase*) ?  If so, change it to return (id) instead.  You'll notice that most initializers in Cocoa return (id) for this very reason.

Instead of

```
- (ModelBase*)init;
```

you want

```
- (id)init;
```