# Inheritance and Casting Return Type

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a child class ParseChild that inherits from parent class PFObject:

**ParseChild.h**

```
@interface ParseChild : PFObject

+(void)findAllWithCompletion:(void(^)(ParseChild *child))handler;

@end
```

**ParseChild.m** (The findAllWithCompletion returns an array of PFObjects).

```
@implementation ParseChild

+(void)findAllWithCompletion:(void(^)(ParseChild *child))handler {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"TagRelationship"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *children, NSError *error) {
       ParseChild *child = (ParseChild *) children[0];
       handler(child);
    }];
}

-(void)deleteWithCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL succeeded))handler {
    [self deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        handler(succeeded);
    }];
}

}
```

I then call the findAllWithCompletion method in my viewcontroller:

```
[ParseChild findAllWithCompletion:^(ParseChild *child) {
     [child deleteWithCompletion:^(BOOL succeeded) {
     }];       
}];
```

Even though I cast the PFObject parent instance as a ParseChild (ParseChild *child = (ParseChild *) children[0];), it is giving me this error:

> -[PFObject deleteWithCompletion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16f77fa0.

Is there something I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just because you cast an object does not mean that you change the object's type.  Your PFQuery returns PFObjects.  The PFObject was compiled to respond to a select number of selectors, and `deleteWithCompletion` was not one of them.  I think you are looking more for the functionality of a category rather than a subclass.

```
@implementation PFObject()
+(void)findAllWithCompletion:(void(^)(ParseChild *child))handler {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"TagRelationship"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *children, NSError *error) {
       PFobject *child = children[0];
       handler(child);
    }];
}

-(void)deleteWithCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL succeeded))handler {
    [self deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        handler(succeeded);
    }];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Putz, but I would rather use inheritance, as I have many types of different PFObjects. With that being said, is there any way that you can see this being possible with inheritance?

Comment: I can't say I know anything about PFQuery's and PFObjects, so I'm not sure how to modify them to suit your needs.  I would create the category, then change the code inside that category to be different depending on your different object types that can be found.

Comment: Not sure if this is specific to PFQueries and PFObjects. I will do some tests to find out...

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should try using ***id type*** rather than class name.
[Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3340675/1307844)

You can also do a type checking as described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3340675/1307844)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, prefer categories over inheritance if you are not able to modify the base class

**PFObject+Search.h**

```
@interface PFObject (Search)
+(void)findAllWithCompletion:(void(^)(PFObject *child))handler;
-(void)deleteWithCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL succeeded))handler;
@end
```

**PFObject+Search.m**

```
@implementation PFObject (Search)
+(void)findAllWithCompletion:(void(^)(PFObject *child))handler {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"TagRelationship"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *children, NSError *error) {

        handler([children firstObject]);
    }];
}

-(void)deleteWithCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL succeeded))handler {
    [self deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        handler(succeeded);
    }];
}
@end
```